# How to add a working sorting to my table?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a problem with sorting, am a beginner at this also, so don't know what to do anymore. I am trying to make a site for school project. I tried many other options, this is what I have now, maybe I went in a wrong way,but the problem is I really don't know. Like I wrote, am a beginner her, hope someone could help. Also first th is blank because of my positioning, don't know really how to position this also. If I don't have a blank TH the Ime is above picture not the name of the game.

Here's my code below:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table,
    rows,
    switching,
    i,
    x,
    y,
    shouldSwitch,
    dir,
    switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#prijava">Prijava</a></li>
    <li><a href="#registracija">Registracija</a></li>
    <div class="onas">
      <li><a href="#onas">O nas</a></li>
    </div>
</nav>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Ime</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Opis</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Ocena</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/9nGoBZ0MRbi6rdH47sj2Qg__thumb/img/ezXcyEsHhS9iRxmuGe8SmiLLXlM=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic5786795.jpg" alt="Monopoly"></td>
    <td>Monopoly</td>
    <td>2-8 igralcev. Trajanje igre 180 minut.</td>
    <td>50</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/7SrPNGBKg9IIsP4UQpOi8g__thumb/img/gAxzddRVQiRdjZHYFUZ2xc5Jlbw=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic4325841.jpg" alt="Star Wars: Rebellion"></td>
    <td>Star Wars: Rebellion</td>
    <td>2-4 igralcev. Trajanje igre 240 min.</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/wg9oOLcsKvDesSUdZQ4rxw__thumb/img/BTxqxgYay5tHJfVoJ2NF5g43_gA=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic3536616.jpg" alt="Terraforming Mars"></td>
    <td>Terraforming Mars</td>
    <td>1-5 igralcev. Trajanje igre 120 min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/ImPgGag98W6gpV1KV812aA__thumb/img/X-lBBdG4uO6LT0y1vXxCN4jdR4M=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic1215633.jpg" alt="War of the Ring: Second Edition"></td>
    <td>War of the Ring: Second Edition</td>
    <td>1-5 igralcev. Trajanje igre 120 min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/w0ZzhcxnGk6VbMrOpZhUTg__thumb/img/w3ruv1OpGPKa4HFbl2n1Oh_5vUI=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic59467.jpg" alt="Airplay"></td>
    <td>Airplay</td>
    <td>2-6 igralcev. Trajanje igre 90 min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/5VDnpX_3ykgCjTJSmHdfCA__thumb/img/LLHF9t1MxB0m-NBe_C9cxAyIslA=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic2884509.jpg" alt="Junk Art"></td>
    <td>Junk Art</td>
    <td>2-6 igralcev. Trajanje igre 30 min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/CH5slprDxeQxJ6ycgViMpA__thumb/img/-cbJd7VCHOgeiTEoCzV5iaynIwQ=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic825679.jpg" alt="Dread House"></td>
    <td>Dread House</td>
    <td>2-6 igralcev. Trajanje igre 90 min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://cf.geekdo-images.com/5tCMB5hjWBNs-kD4DSEZMw__thumb/img/rWjN-iR4gWM69bz8aCSnGl74vrw=/fit-in/200x150/filters:strip_icc()/pic299522.jpg" alt="Get the Gem"></td>
    <td>Get the Gem</td>
    <td>2 igralca. Trajanje igre / min.</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It's okay that you're first trying to coding your project. But we need to know, what is the problem you're facing with? Could you explain what you're trying to sort, and into what, like explain the result you want. And also please explain why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Well I am trying to sort games in alphabeth order when I click on Ime (name) and  Ocena (rating) from lowest to highest. Well and it is not working, not even that it sorts the wrong way.